# Android: load only detail of large image

Tags: android, out-of-memory, large-files, imagemap

I'm working on a project that needs to use a large image as a map. The image is about 95MB and has a resolution of 12100 x 8000 pixels.

I don't need the whole image at once, I just need a detail of 1000 x 1000 Pixel (it's not always the same detail, just grabbing the same part is not a solution I can use).  So I can't just sample it down with the `BitmapOptions`.

I looked around and found the idea to create a `FileInputStream` (the image is on the SD-Card) and then I can just load the detail with `decodeStream(InputStream is, Rect outPadding, BitmapFactory.Options opts)`. That way I wouldn't load the whole thing into the memory. I tried it, but it's just crashing when I try to load the image. Here's my code:

```
FileInputStream stream = null;
try {
    stream = new FileInputStream(path);
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("inputstream",e.toString());
}
Rect rect = new Rect(a,b,c,d);
return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, rect, null);
```

When I try to load the image, the activity closes and LogCat tells me `java.lang.outOfMemoryError`. Why does it crash? I thought with the stream it should work on the image "on-the-fly", but the only explication I have for the Error is the it trys to load the hole image into the memory. Does anybody have an idea how I can load the detail out of the image, or why this idea doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does BitmapRegionDecoder not help (I realise its level 10)?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was searching for. It's funny that it's nowhere mentioned, even on the officel reference there's a site about big images, but it's just explaining how to use the inSampleSize, and theres not a word about the 'BitmapRegionDecoder'. However, when I was using it, it still crashed. I found out by accident, when I just give the Decoder a BitmapFactory.Options with SampleSize 1, instead of just call 'decodeRegion' with '(rect, null)' (which is allowed!), the problem is solved, I don't know why, but its working :-) . I think I will use a combination of tiles and RegionDecoder

Answer (score 1):

It crashed because all these 95M are sucked into memory for processing. This call will not ignore parts of the stream - it will put the whole thing to memory and then try to manipulate it. The only solution you can have is to have some sort of server side code that does the same sort of manipulation or if you don't want to do it on server - provide thumbnails of your large image. And I would strongly advise against pulling whole 95M at any time anyways

Comment: Or go with a tile-based solution, like some game apps do, where the large image is packaged not as a single monolithic whole, but rather as a series of tiles, and you just load in the tile you want.

Comment: Also you can overimpose smaller image(s) on the generated background creating illusion of one large image